# Lucene.Net.3.0 NRT with Azure Directory

Tags: c#, azure, lucene, lucene.net

I want to implement full text search for a CMS application deployed on Azure cloud service utilizing Lucene.Net Near Real Time Search capabilities. In order to do this, I thought about having a factory generate a singleton instance of the IndexWriter, and thus read requests can use this singleton instance to open/reopen an NRT IndexReader that has latest uncommitted or committed documents.

Most blog articles illustrate delegating the IndexWriter to a worker role instance as it is resource intensive. So my question here is how do I share a singleton instance between multiple Azure roles, namely web role that will consume a read/write service and a worker role that handles indexing in the back end. Or, does it even make sense to delegate IndexWrtier to a separate role when using NRT approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delegate IndexWrtier to a separate worker role and use NRT search from another instance.

However, you can place IndexWrtier on separate worker role that will index documents on shared resource (like file share, blob storage, etc) and then create IndexReader on another Web/Worker Role that will use this resource.

You can use [AzureDirectory Library for Lucene.Net](https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/) if you want to use Azure Blob Storage.

It is also worth to try [Azure File Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) for storing shared index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am leaning towards Azure Service Bus as the mechanism for the Web role to transport messages to the Worker role because of its push notification features. The articles I read use Azure cloud storage queue instead, but upon reading further about it I don't like the idea of polling for messages frequently especially when there are no new messages since that would be a sunk cost. The use case here is that there won't be frequent content creation, but the expectation is near real time search of new content.